# Switching forms with $_GET value or Creating a different page for each form in PHP

Tags: php, include

If I switch forms, I'd use this on the index.php

```
switch($_GET["action"]) {
case "login": include "login.php";break; //loads login form 
case "register": include "register.php";break; //loads register form 
}
```

If I use different pages for each form, I'd need to include the headers, footers and other stuff in each page.

for login, user would enter:

```
index.php?action="login"
```

or

```
login.php
```

Which one is more common and practical?

Comment: I prefer `if (file_exists("{$_GET['action']}.php")) include "{$_GET['action']}.php"; else include "default.php";` - with the appropriate sanitization and permissions checking, of course...

Comment: @DaveRandom that creates too much of a security code- clutter

Comment: I would just `include("./{$_GET->name->in_array("action", "login,register")}.php");`. - As for your actual question: that's a matter of preference. Dispatcher scripts are more common, and reveal less about the internal implementation. But url rewriting should prettify either.

Answer (score 0):

If you go with the former option, you'd need to consider what would happen if a user were to visit those pages (e.g login.php) directly: are those included files accessible via a browser? If so, you might consider putting them outside the Web directory and in their own folder. If that's not possible, you could implement some check in the login.php/register.php scripts:

```
if (__FILE__ === $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']) {
     // user visited script directly, rather than included
}
```

The other option is more commonly used (especially if all your files sit in the Web root), provided that the logic required to include headers, footers, config scripts etc. is kept simple, otherwise you'll have to change it in a number of locations.

**Summary:** I'd advise adding simple `include` calls for header and footer scripts on each page, unless you can put the included files somewhere outside the Web root.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably most common practice to have a separate function for handling each type of form post. These you can store in a single PHP file or multiple files and include in your pages. It is ok but not so much common practice to selectively include various php scripts.

For your layout there are various solutions possible each with its own advantages and disadvantages, depending on your website or application, but it is hard to tell whats best other than never to have duplicate code.